# Create a P2P network between smartphones over WiFi

Tags: android, ios, sockets, networking, wifi

I want to create an app for smartphones which will be able to connect devices between them over WiFi to transfer data.

My needs are :

- Create a P2P group over WiFi and become the group owner
- Every smartphones can join it no matter OSes (mostly android and IOS)
- every devices in the group can send messages to the group owner
- group owner can send messages to every devices in the group
- each device can be connected on their own WiFi network to access internet (or no network at all) and be able to join the P2P group anyway (Without been disconnected from their actual network).
- no limitation on how much devices can join the group

I wonder if a technology with following constraints exists :

- create a network between smartphone WiFi devices no matter OSes
- smartphones doesn't have to be on a same network to find each other (I mean they may be connected on their own network over WiFi to access internet and be able to see each other to create a P2P network in parallel)
- No need of an internet connection
- I think limitation of simultaneous connection on one WiFi device hot spot is nearly 10 (depending on device specifications). It will be perfect if each WiFi device may be a rooter for this network. If it does, there will be no limitation anymore.
- advertise services over the network.

To sum up it will pretty much works like actual internet network but with smartphones as rooter.

I saw lot of resources but it seems that none of them fit my needs :

**WiFi Direct** : Only for android devices. Only one group owner (max simultaneous connection limitation).

**aircrack** : not sure on how does this one works. Not seems that the main purpose is to create a network.

**AllJoyn** : Seems all devices need to be on a single WiFi network to communicate.

**Open peers** : Need an internet connection.

**MultipeerConnectivity** : For IOS devices.

I may be wrong on above technology analysis, let me know if I am.
May be there is no way that a solution which cover all my needs may exists  because of physical limitation.

Comment: No. This is nice fantasy.

Comment: Which ones of above specifications are impossible to achieve ?